# jQuery UI datepicker image loading before focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've got a date picker (popUpDatepicker) in a div which isn't displayed when the form is loaded. After an event the div is displayed and the datepicker initialised as follows:

```
  $("#popUpDatepicker").datepicker({
                showOn: 'focus',
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                maxDate: "0",
                showAnim: "fadeIn",
                theme: "Cupertino"
            }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

The first time the div is loaded (after the page is loaded) the calendar image appears off to the left of the screen. If I focus on the input the calendar moves to the correct place (when the div is loaded the input does not have focus). When the div is loaded for a second time the calendar does not appear until the input is given focus. If I remove the setDate call the calendar does not appear until the input is given focus.

I don't want the calendar to appear until the input has focus. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your problem here.  Would you mind providing the HTML that you have along with the above JS code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question but datepicker loads when the input is on focus.